# Changing the Odata service of WebIDE Archive (FIORI APP)

Tags: data-binding, odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

For reasons of security I cannot use the cloud connector in conjunction with the on premise system which we have. Never the less I am very comfortable using WebIDE in order to create the necessary applications. I create the applications in WebIDE using a .edmx file which represents the on premise ODATA service which i plan to use.

After the application is made. I import the archive and then make necessary modifications to the archive in HANA Studio (inside Java EE perspective).

I am doing things according to this guide: https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/hcp-webide-switch-live-odata.html

My understanding is that the manifest.json and neo-app.json are both to be modified pointing to the real ODATA service.

In the manifest.json:

[image]

According to the guide above, within the neo-app.json, I need to point it to the gateway.

Here is the information of our on premise system.

System Name: sapewp01.xxxxx.com

localURI: /sap/opu/odata/sap/zbw_odata_q3_srv/

Port: 8012 (i assume, the odata service link works on my end)

SAP Gateway (sapgw12)

Another other required information can be provided on request.

How does one change a web ide app to be able link into an on premise ODATA service, WITHOUT disrupting all the work done on webIDE?

Answer (score 0):

In the sap.app part of the `manifest.json` can't you just specify?

```
"dataSources": {
    "myService": {
        "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/zbw_odata_q3_srv/",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
            "odataVersion": "2.0"
        }
    }
}
```

At least with my experience working in Eclipse, all I had to do was have the URI to create the model.
`oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, oConfig);`
but this was using a legacy app, maybe Web IDE does it a different way?

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  The thing I don't understand how giving just the URI points it to the correct odata service.  Wouldn't the whole link need to be fed to the app in some manner? Webide has an odd practice of defining destinations.  Where exactly it acquires this from? I don't know. It must be a part of the app right?

Comment: https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/hcp-webide-switch-live-odata.html --You can see in that tutorial that you create a destination in the hana cloud cockpit and then point it to that destination.    In many of those steps they always refer it to the destination.  look at step 6 and 7.   Step 2 gives you the information that is in the destination that is created.  There is no destination file within the webide archive.   How do I create my own destination file and point to it?

Comment: on a side note.oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, oConfig); when you say this.  What exactly do you mean regarding oConfig.  I have defined the sServiceUrl

Comment: I think the odata service and web app resided in the same base web url, so it knew how to find it just based on the URI. Again I did this on eclipse which might be different from the webide. The oConfig is a bunch of properties that you can provide to the constructor, you can see them here https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html

Comment: you can check if the odata model is in the same system by loading it's metadata. try something like this: if your website is mywebsiteholder.com:404/myapp/website/index.html then go to mywebsiteholder.com:404/URI_OF_ODATA SERVICE/$metadata, if it loads then you should be good to use what I provided. I guess tldr put the service in the same place as your website and then you can use the URI.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more in detail where you have security concerns using Cloud Connector?
Cloud Connector works as reverse proxy and is designed for secure connections.

Comment: First and foremost, my company does not trust it.  Secondly, configuration is not working for me even if it was accepted. I am sure I have all the credentials correct. I would also state further that the apps must run internally on the fiori launchpad that they have setup internally. This "destination" business makes the process of importing the application and running it difficult.

Comment: This is the whole problem. SAP Fiori guidelines state that it is against their explicit policy/reccomendation to use a link inside of the component.js for UI5 apps. Yet they have very little in the form of detailed documents which express how the destination relationship connects the application to the credentials of the ODATA service

Comment: so when you do a odataservice/$metadata.  you can just bind those in the views {variable}. the data is bound right, have you ever specified anything in the controller?